# Discretize pick up data longitude and latitude in grids

Tags: r

I have taxi pickup data in terms of latitude and longitude in Newyork.
1. I want to discretize data into grids of 2km and carry out further calculations with data in each grid.
2. The code should be flexible to easily change the grid size if needed.
3.

Sample pickup data-

```
pickup_longitude    pickup_latitude
-73.9903717 40.73469543
-73.98078156    40.7299118
-73.98455048    40.67956543
-73.99346924    40.71899033
-73.96062469    40.78133011
-73.9801178 40.74304962
-73.9940567 40.71998978
-73.97942352    40.74461365
-73.94715118    40.79104614
-73.99834442    40.72389603
-74.00614929    40.74491882
-73.96932983    40.76353836
-73.9890213 40.72153854
-74.00430298    40.74224091
-73.99199677    40.71857834
-73.98516083    40.76895142
-73.97309113    40.79536057
-73.98210144    40.77469635
-73.99484253    40.71849823
-73.95303345    40.67211533
-73.98916626    40.7265892
-73.99906921    40.72017288
-73.99713898    40.74721909
-73.99741364    40.73667526
```

I have used raster package and tried to create the grid. I want to visualize the grid and also run a loop to collect data from a grid within 
latitude (40.757295,40.817147) and longitude (-73.994057-73.929255)

```
  min_lat <- 40.5774
 max_lat <- 40.9176
 min_long <- -74.15
   max_long <- -73.7004

  #make raster
  size_raster <- 3/110.574 #
  nlat <- ceiling((max_lat - min_lat)/size_raster)
     r <- raster(ncol=nlat, xmn=min_long, ymn=min_lat, xmx=max_long,           ymx=max_lat)
  ncol(r) <- nlat
  nrow(r) <- nlat
  r[] <- 0
  ngrid <- nlat^2
```

Comment: 1 and 2 are clear, but what does point 3 mean?

Comment: After creating the grids, I want to run a for loop and conduct tests within a single grid of a specific area in new york city.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? We usually don't just "write your code" for you. Put in the first bit of effort and edit your question with code you've attempted and why it is not working. (Given that, I'd possible use a combination of `range`, `seq`, and possibly `expand.grid`, though the latter can start getting "expensive" with larger areas.)

Comment: I have edited my question. Please guide about how to proceed